# Odoo Point Of Sale : Add button to print a different receipt format? Odoo 13

Tags: javascript, python, xml, odoo

I added another button to print receipt.So, one that prints the default receipt when clicked and another that prints a different template. Here is my code which print the same receipt , my question is how to modify for the second button another template similar to the default with some modifications.
Any help please? Thanks.

```
odoo.define('pos_print.pos_report', function (require) { "use
    strict";
    var screens = require('point_of_sale.screens'); console.log("screens
    : " + screens)
    var gui = require('point_of_sale.gui'); var core =
    require('web.core'); var _t = core._t;
    screens.ReceiptScreenWidget.include({
      renderElement: function() {
            var self = this;
            this._super();
            this.$('.next').click(function(){
                if (!self._locked) {
                    self.click_next();
                }
            });
            this.$('.back').click(function(){
                if (!self._locked) {
                    self.click_back();
                }
            });
            this.$('.button.order-print').click(function(){
                if (!self._locked) {
                    self.print();
                }
            });
    
        },
    
    
    }); });



<templates id="point_of_sale.template" xml:space="preserve">
    <t t-extend="ReceiptScreenWidget">
       <t t-jquery=".button.print" t-operation="after">
           <div class="button order-print">
               <i class='fa fa-print'></i>
               Print POS Order
           </div>
       </t>    </t> </templates>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to create new print method in ReceiptScreenWidget:

```
renderElement: function() {
    var self = this;
    this._super();
    this.$('.next').click(function(){
        if (!self._locked) {
            self.click_next();
        }
    });
    this.$('.back').click(function(){
        if (!self._locked) {
            self.click_back();
        }
    });
    this.$('.button.print').click(function(){
        if (!self._locked) {
            self.print();
        }
    });

    this.$('.button.order-print').click(function(){
        // To print new format
        if (!self._locked) {
            self.myPrint();
        }
    });

},

myPrint: function () {
    // MyNewOrderReceipt is your new receipt template
    // YOUR_PARAMS is parameters required in your template
    var receipt = QWeb.render('MyNewOrderReceipt', YOUR_PARAMS);

    this.pos.proxy.printer.print_receipt(receipt);
    this.pos.get_order()._printed = true;
    this.lock_screen(false);
},
```

note: this is assuming you are aiming to print the new template directly to printer without preview, if you want to change the receipt screen you need to override ActionButtonWidget.

Comment: I added new template <t t-name="MyNewOrderReceipt"> in which I will print only receipt.company.logo ; then what should be the params 'YOUR_PARAMS', can you give me an example please?Thanks.

Comment: when adding data : var receipt = QWeb.render('MyNewOrderReceipt', this.get_receipt_render_env());  , I got this error Uncaught ReferenceError: QWeb is not defined
http://localhost:8069/web/content/849-3c2b99c/point_of_sale.assets.js:519
Retraçage :

Comment: add this to your js file:

    var core = require('web.core');
    var QWeb = core.qweb;

Comment: 'YOUR_PARAMS' is the parameters you needed in your template, but if you don't need any parameters just don't pass the YOUR_PARAMS variable to render function, like this var receipt = QWeb.render('MyNewOrderReceipt');

Comment: Uncaught Error: QWeb2: Template 'MyNewOrderReceipt' not found
http://localhost:8069/web/content/823-0ffc093/web.assets_common.js:3692

Comment: you need to create the 'MyNewOrderReceipt' template

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227783/discussion-between-ing-and-sdbot).